# how to display entity references as numbered list?

Tags: views, entities, commerce

I'm selling music albums in Commerce. The product type has an entity reference field with unlimited values for the content type 'tracks' which I'm using to display the tracklist of an album. I'd like to output this field as a numbered list so the track I reference are displayed like this:

1. track title
2. track title
   etc.

I also need to be able to export the track number from a View via Views Data Export.

Any ideas as to how achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple, in this example **I will use title instead of an entity reference field**, but it's the same process.

**Step 1)** add `Global: View result counter` as a field.

[image]

**Step 2)** Uncheck create label, and checkmark hide from display.

[image]

**Step 3)** Re-arrange so your counter is above your entity reference field.

[image]

**Step 4)** Re-write results and **use replacement patterns** to format your title field.

[image]

Comment: The OP asked about creating a numbered list with the unlimited values of a single field. This will probably involve using a views field to create a sub-view of only the values of this particular field and embed it within the view of the entity

Comment: @argiepiano the question was tagged with the views tag.

Comment: hi @argiepiano. Sorry about the long wait. I actually need to be able to do both (display the list in a view and on a node). ANy thoughts on how to do it on a node?

Comment: Something like that would involve creating a new "view mode" for the referred entities (for example with modules Display Suite or Entity view modes) and tweaking the template  to add the numbered bullet. Ask a new question if you want more detailed explanations